# Post to several friend's timeline via FaceBook feed dialog

Tags: android, facebook

Since request "id/feed" was deprecated, I'm trying to implement Facebook feed dialog to post to user's friends timelines.

I found in documentation parameter "to", where I can define ID of the user post to.

But if I want to post one message to several friends, how can I do that?

I'm trying to use something like "user_id_1,user_id_2,user_id_3" but it does not work.

Comment: You can’t. The description in the docs says “the ID or user name” – singular – for a reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
It is good that FriendPickerFragment from Facebook sdk provides single mode selection of friends)

Comment: @CBroe Is there any way to do that?